# vim -- How to read range of lines from a file into current buffer

Tags: vim

I want to read line n1->n2 from file foo.c into the current buffer.

I tried: `147,227r /path/to/foo/foo.c`

But I get: "E16: Invalid range", though I am certain that foo.c contains more than 1000 lines.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
:r! sed -n 147,227p /path/to/foo/foo.c
```

Comment: any chance you know how to build a copy / paste macro for multiple vim's in tmux, enabling pasting from one file to another?

Comment: I tried above, however when trying to read 217 lines, then the last 18 lines swapped around to the front of the insertion point in vim - do you know why this could happen? is there a wrap around when 200 lines have been reached ?

Answer (score 33):

You can do it in pure Vimscript, without having to use an external tool like sed:

```
:put =readfile('/path/to/foo/foo.c')[146:226]
```

Note that we must **decrement one** from the line numbers because arrays start from 0 while line numbers start from 1.

*Disadvantages*: This solution is 7 characters longer than the accepted answer.  It will temporarily read the entire file into memory, which could be a concern if that file is huge.

Comment: Isn't there a way to transform it into a comfortable vim command,  with a syntax similar to the one proposed by OP? e.g. :
`147,227ri /path/to/foo/foo.c' (notice `ri' for read-in)

Comment: Yes you certainly could do that. However user created commands must begin with a capital letter, so your `ri` would need to be `Ri` or `RI`.

Comment: This does no seem to work when using tilde `~/` for the $HOME directory, for example:  `readfile("~/Documents/something.txt")` results in `E484: Can't open file `~/Documents/something.txt`.

Comment: Actually, I found I could do this with the `expand()` command like so: `:put =readfile(expand('~/Documents/something.txt'))`

Answer (score 23):

The {range} refers to the destination in the current file, not the range of lines in the source file.

After some experimentation, it seems

```
:147,227r /path/to/foo/foo.c
```

means *insert the contents of `/path/to/foo/foo.c` after line 227 in this file.* i.e.: it ignores the 147.

Answer (score 13):

Other solutions posted are great for specific line numbers. It's often the case that you want to read from top or bottom of another file. In that case, reading the output of head or tail is very fast. For example -

```
:r !head -20 xyz.xml
```

Will read first 20 lines from xyz.xml into current buffer where the cursor is

```
:r !tail -10 xyz.xml
```

Will read last 10 lines from xyz.xml into current buffer where the cursor is

The head and tail commands are extremely fast, therefore even combining them can be much faster than other approaches for very large files.

```
:r !head -700030 xyz.xml| tail -30
```

Will read line numbers from 700000 to 700030 from file xyz.xml into current buffer

This operation should complete instantly even for fairly large files.

Answer (score 4):

I just had to do this in a code project of mine and did it this way:

In buffer with `/path/to/foo/foo.c` open:

```
:147,227w export.txt
```

In buffer I'm working with:

```
:r export.txt
```

Much easier in my book...  It requires having both files open, but if I'm importing a set of lines, I usually have them both open anyway.  This method is more general and easier to remember for me, especially if I'm trying to export/import a trickier set of lines using `g/<search_criteria/:.w >> export.txt` or some other more complicated way of selecting lines.

Comment: This one begs the question -- if you have the file open and you are going to input the range, why not just yank that range and put it into the target buffer?

Comment: @DigitalAce69  does this provide you need to be in the same directory because the cut lines are saved as a file? This would mean it does not work editing files in different locations!?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to:

```
:r /path/to/foo/foo.c
:d 228,$
:d 1,146
```

Three steps, but it will get it done...

Comment: this is so much typing  , sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

> A range permits a command to be applied to a group of lines in the current buffer.

So, the range of read instruction means where to insert the content in the current file, but not the range of file that you want to read.